# Downloaded file is larger size than one being sent

Tags: java, http, io, byte, arrays

I have a http request which gets a file from a server and then downloads it in Java. The problem is that the file which I download is 2 bytes larger than the one being sent.

This is how I'm writing the response file.

```
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
    int n = - 1;

    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(downloadsPath + formattedHeaders[0].toString());
    while ( (n = input.read(buffer)) != -1) 
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    input.close();
    output.close();
```

I use the file size then compare it to the file size sent in the header to see if I have the full file downloaded. The server size is fine and is getting the right size and adding it to the headers. Somehow while i'm writing the file it gets extra 2 bytes.

Comment: Can you check this last two bytes from the file? I think it's a separator of the HTTP multipart formatting or chunked encoding separator.

Comment: Also check if your file has some special characters that are encoded differently in both (request and downloaded) files.

Comment: The hash doesn't matter, as the file size changes in the transition of sending. (before I compare hashes).

Comment: [80, 75, -------------- 79, 107]  Here you can see the first two bytes in the byte[] and the last two bytes in the byte[].

Comment: What we need is the first and last bytes of *both* files to control where the transfer could have added trailing bytes

Comment: I found the problem, after writing the file on the server side it also wrote "Ok" to the response. This was the final two bytes at the end [79, 107]. Thanks for all the input and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the response doesn't match the file is because the response which is sent also had "Ok" concatenated. The last two bytes [79, 107] when converted to ASCII represent "Ok". Removing this "Ok" on the server side so its not sent fixes the issue.